# SAS Character Comparisons

Tags: string, sas, dataset

I'm very new at SAS and I have a problem. I have a dataset like this:
[Dataset_idchemo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVDes.png)
and I want to create a new dummy variable with 0 `if Chemo = NonTreated else 1`, but idk why I can't, the result is a column with only zeros and a bunch of warnings like `" Invalid numeric data, 'Treated' , at line 74 column 13."` 
My code is:

```
data new; 
    set readm;
chemio = 0;
if chemo =: 'Treated' then chemio = 1; 
run;
```

Thanks!

PS: this is my dataset, I don't know if this is the right way to add it here, let me know what's the best way. 
There are four columns `Oss` it's the number of the observation, `id`, `event` (0 or 1) and `chemo` ("Treated", "NonTreated")

```
Oss id  event   chemo
1   1   1   Treated
2   1   1   Treated
3   1   0   Treated
4   2   1   NonTreated
5   2   0   NonTreated
6   3   1   NonTreated
7   3   0   NonTreated
8   4   1   Treated
9   4   1   Treated
10  4   1   Treated
11  4   1   Treated
12  4   0   Treated
13  5   1   NonTreated
14  5   0   NonTreated
15  6   1   Treated
16  6   1   Treated
17  6   1   Treated
18  6   0   Treated
19  7   1   Treated
20  7   1   Treated
21  7   1   Treated
22  7   0   Treated
23  8   0   NonTreated
24  9   1   NonTreated
25  9   0   NonTreated
26  10  0   Treated
27  11  1   Treated
28  11  1   Treated
29  11  0   Treated
30  12  0   Treated
31  13  1   NonTreated
32  13  0   NonTreated
33  14  0   Treated
34  15  1   NonTreated
35  15  1   NonTreated
36  15  0   NonTreated
37  16  1   NonTreated
38  16  0   NonTreated
39  17  0   NonTreated
40  18  0   Treated
41  19  0   Treated
42  20  1   Treated
43  20  0   Treated
44  21  1   Treated
45  21  0   Treated
46  22  0   Treated
47  23  1   Treated
48  23  0   Treated
49  24  1   Treated
50  24  0   Treated
51  25  0   Treated
52  26  0   Treated
53  27  0   Treated
54  28  0   NonTreated
55  29  1   Treated
56  29  0   Treated
57  30  0   Treated
58  31  1   Treated
59  31  0   Treated
60  32  1   NonTreated
61  32  1   NonTreated
62  32  0   NonTreated
63  33  1   Treated
64  33  1   Treated
65  33  1   Treated
66  33  0   Treated
67  34  0   Treated
68  35  1   Treated
69  35  0   Treated
70  36  0   Treated
71  37  1   NonTreated
72  37  1   NonTreated
73  37  0   NonTreated
74  38  0   NonTreated
75  39  0   Treated
76  40  1   Treated
77  40  1   Treated
78  40  1   Treated
79  40  1   Treated
80  40  1   Treated
81  40  1   Treated
82  40  0   Treated
83  41  1   Treated
84  41  0   Treated
85  42  1   Treated
86  42  1   Treated
87  42  0   Treated
88  43  1   Treated
89  43  1   Treated
90  43  0   Treated
91  44  1   NonTreated
92  44  0   NonTreated
93  45  0   NonTreated
94  46  0   Treated
95  47  0   NonTreated
96  48  0   NonTreated
97  49  1   NonTreated
98  49  0   NonTreated
99  50  1   NonTreated
100 50  0   NonTreated
101 51  1   NonTreated
102 51  1   NonTreated
103 51  0   NonTreated
104 52  1   NonTreated
105 52  1   NonTreated
106 52  1   NonTreated
107 52  1   NonTreated
108 52  0   NonTreated
109 53  1   Treated
110 53  1   Treated
111 53  0   Treated
112 54  1   NonTreated
113 54  0   NonTreated
114 55  0   Treated
115 56  0   Treated
116 57  0   NonTreated
117 58  0   Treated
118 59  0   Treated
119 60  1   NonTreated
120 60  0   NonTreated
121 61  0   Treated
122 62  0   Treated
123 63  0   Treated
124 64  1   Treated
125 64  0   Treated
126 65  1   Treated
127 65  0   Treated
128 66  0   Treated
129 67  0   NonTreated
130 68  1   NonTreated
131 68  0   NonTreated
132 69  0   Treated
133 70  0   Treated
134 71  1   Treated
135 71  1   Treated
136 71  0   Treated
137 72  0   Treated
138 73  0   Treated
139 74  0   NonTreated
140 75  0   Treated
141 76  1   NonTreated
142 76  1   NonTreated
143 76  0   NonTreated
144 77  0   NonTreated
145 78  1   NonTreated
146 78  1   NonTreated
147 78  1   NonTreated
148 78  1   NonTreated
149 78  0   NonTreated
150 79  1   Treated
151 79  0   Treated
152 80  0   NonTreated
153 81  0   NonTreated
154 82  1   NonTreated
155 82  0   NonTreated
156 83  1   Treated
157 83  0   Treated
158 84  1   NonTreated
159 84  0   NonTreated
160 85  0   Treated
161 86  1   Treated
162 86  1   Treated
163 86  0   Treated
164 87  1   Treated
165 87  0   Treated
166 88  1   NonTreated
167 88  0   NonTreated
168 89  0   Treated
169 90  0   Treated
170 91  1   NonTreated
171 91  1   NonTreated
172 91  0   NonTreated
173 92  0   NonTreated
174 93  1   NonTreated
175 93  1   NonTreated
176 93  1   NonTreated
177 93  0   NonTreated
178 94  1   Treated
179 94  0   Treated
180 95  0   Treated
181 96  0   Treated
182 97  1   Treated
183 97  1   Treated
184 97  1   Treated
185 97  0   Treated
186 98  1   Treated
187 98  1   Treated
188 98  0   Treated
189 99  0   NonTreated
190 100 1   NonTreated
191 100 0   NonTreated
192 101 0   Treated
193 102 1   Treated
194 102 1   Treated
195 102 0   Treated
196 103 1   NonTreated
197 103 0   NonTreated
198 104 0   NonTreated
199 105 0   NonTreated
200 106 0   Treated
201 107 0   Treated
202 108 1   Treated
203 108 0   Treated
204 109 1   NonTreated
205 109 0   NonTreated
206 110 0   Treated
207 111 0   Treated
208 112 0   Treated
209 113 0   NonTreated
210 114 1   NonTreated
211 114 1   NonTreated
212 114 1   NonTreated
213 114 1   NonTreated
214 114 1   NonTreated
215 114 1   NonTreated
216 114 1   NonTreated
217 114 1   NonTreated
218 114 1   NonTreated
219 114 0   NonTreated
220 115 1   NonTreated
221 115 1   NonTreated
222 115 0   NonTreated
223 116 0   NonTreated
224 117 1   NonTreated
225 117 0   NonTreated
226 118 1   Treated
227 118 0   Treated
228 119 1   NonTreated
229 119 0   NonTreated
230 120 0   NonTreated
231 121 0   NonTreated
232 122 1   NonTreated
233 122 1   NonTreated
234 122 1   NonTreated
235 122 1   NonTreated
236 122 0   NonTreated
237 123 0   Treated
238 124 0   NonTreated
239 125 1   Treated
240 125 0   Treated
241 126 1   Treated
242 126 0   Treated
243 127 0   NonTreated
244 128 1   NonTreated
245 128 0   NonTreated
246 129 1   NonTreated
247 129 1   NonTreated
248 129 0   NonTreated
249 130 0   Treated
250 131 1   NonTreated
251 131 1   NonTreated
252 131 1   NonTreated
253 131 1   NonTreated
254 131 0   NonTreated
255 132 1   NonTreated
256 132 0   NonTreated
257 133 1   NonTreated
258 133 1   NonTreated
259 133 1   NonTreated
260 133 0   NonTreated
261 134 1   NonTreated
262 134 0   NonTreated
263 135 1   NonTreated
264 135 1   NonTreated
265 135 1   NonTreated
266 135 1   NonTreated
267 135 0   NonTreated
268 136 1   NonTreated
269 136 1   NonTreated
270 136 1   NonTreated
271 136 1   NonTreated
272 136 0   NonTreated
273 137 0   NonTreated
274 138 1   Treated
275 138 1   Treated
276 138 1   Treated
277 138 0   Treated
278 139 0   NonTreated
279 140 0   Treated
280 141 1   Treated
281 141 1   Treated
282 141 1   Treated
283 141 0   Treated
284 142 1   Treated
285 142 0   Treated
286 143 1   NonTreated
287 143 0   NonTreated
288 144 1   Treated
289 144 0   Treated
290 145 0   Treated
291 146 1   NonTreated
292 146 0   NonTreated
293 147 1   Treated
294 147 1   Treated
295 147 1   Treated
296 147 1   Treated
297 147 0   Treated
298 148 1   Treated
299 148 0   Treated
300 149 1   Treated
301 149 1   Treated
302 149 0   Treated
303 150 1   Treated
304 150 0   Treated
305 151 0   Treated
306 152 0   Treated
307 153 1   NonTreated
308 153 1   NonTreated
309 153 0   NonTreated
310 154 1   Treated
311 154 1   Treated
312 154 0   Treated
313 155 0   Treated
314 156 1   Treated
315 156 1   Treated
316 156 0   Treated
317 157 0   Treated
318 158 0   Treated
319 159 0   Treated
320 160 1   Treated
321 160 1   Treated
322 160 0   Treated
323 161 0   NonTreated
324 162 0   Treated
325 163 0   NonTreated
326 164 0   Treated
327 165 0   Treated
328 166 0   NonTreated
329 167 0   Treated
330 168 1   NonTreated
331 168 0   NonTreated
332 169 0   NonTreated
333 170 1   NonTreated
334 170 1   NonTreated
335 170 0   NonTreated
336 171 1   NonTreated
337 171 1   NonTreated
338 171 0   NonTreated
339 172 0   Treated
340 173 0   Treated
341 174 1   Treated
342 174 1   Treated
343 174 1   Treated
344 174 1   Treated
345 174 0   Treated
346 175 0   Treated
347 176 1   Treated
348 176 0   Treated
349 177 1   NonTreated
350 177 1   NonTreated
351 177 0   NonTreated
352 178 0   NonTreated
353 179 0   Treated
354 180 1   Treated
355 180 0   Treated
356 181 0   Treated
357 182 0   NonTreated
358 183 1   Treated
359 183 1   Treated
360 183 1   Treated
361 183 1   Treated
362 183 1   Treated
363 183 0   Treated
364 184 1   NonTreated
365 184 0   NonTreated
366 185 1   NonTreated
367 185 0   NonTreated
368 186 1   NonTreated
369 186 1   NonTreated
370 186 1   NonTreated
371 186 0   NonTreated
372 187 1   NonTreated
373 187 1   NonTreated
374 187 0   NonTreated
375 188 0   Treated
376 189 0   Treated
377 190 1   Treated
378 190 1   Treated
379 190 0   Treated
380 191 1   Treated
381 191 1   Treated
382 191 0   Treated
383 192 1   NonTreated
384 192 1   NonTreated
385 192 1   NonTreated
386 192 0   NonTreated
387 193 0   NonTreated
388 194 1   Treated
389 194 0   Treated
390 195 0   Treated
391 196 0   Treated
392 197 0   NonTreated
393 198 1   Treated
394 198 0   Treated
395 199 1   NonTreated
396 199 0   NonTreated
397 200 0   Treated
398 201 1   Treated
399 201 1   Treated
400 201 1   Treated
401 201 1   Treated
402 201 1   Treated
403 201 1   Treated
404 201 0   Treated
405 202 1   NonTreated
406 202 1   NonTreated
407 202 0   NonTreated
408 203 1   Treated
409 203 0   Treated
410 204 0   NonTreated
411 205 0   Treated
412 206 1   Treated
413 206 0   Treated
414 207 0   Treated
415 208 1   Treated
416 208 0   Treated
417 209 1   Treated
418 209 1   Treated
419 209 1   Treated
420 209 1   Treated
421 209 1   Treated
422 209 1   Treated
423 209 0   Treated
424 210 0   Treated
425 211 0   NonTreated
426 212 1   NonTreated
427 212 1   NonTreated
428 212 1   NonTreated
429 212 0   NonTreated
430 213 0   Treated
431 214 1   Treated
432 214 1   Treated
433 214 1   Treated
434 214 1   Treated
435 214 0   Treated
436 215 0   Treated
437 216 0   Treated
438 217 0   Treated
439 218 0   Treated
440 219 1   NonTreated
441 219 1   NonTreated
442 219 1   NonTreated
443 219 0   NonTreated
444 220 1   Treated
445 220 1   Treated
446 220 0   Treated
447 221 1   Treated
448 221 1   Treated
449 221 0   Treated
450 222 0   Treated
451 223 0   Treated
452 224 1   NonTreated
453 224 0   NonTreated
454 225 0   Treated
455 226 1   NonTreated
456 226 0   NonTreated
457 227 0   NonTreated
458 228 1   Treated
459 228 1   Treated
460 228 1   Treated
461 228 1   Treated
462 228 1   Treated
463 228 0   Treated
464 229 1   Treated
465 229 0   Treated
466 230 0   Treated
467 231 0   Treated
468 232 1   NonTreated
469 232 1   NonTreated
470 232 1   NonTreated
471 232 1   NonTreated
472 232 0   NonTreated
473 233 0   NonTreated
474 234 0   Treated
475 235 1   NonTreated
476 235 1   NonTreated
477 235 0   NonTreated
478 236 0   Treated
479 237 1   NonTreated
480 237 0   NonTreated
481 238 0   Treated
482 239 0   Treated
483 240 1   NonTreated
484 240 1   NonTreated
485 240 0   NonTreated
486 241 1   NonTreated
487 241 0   NonTreated
488 242 1   NonTreated
489 242 1   NonTreated
490 242 0   NonTreated
491 243 1   NonTreated
492 243 1   NonTreated
493 243 1   NonTreated
494 243 0   NonTreated
495 244 0   Treated
496 245 0   Treated
497 246 1   Treated
498 246 0   Treated
499 247 1   Treated
500 247 1   Treated
501 247 0   Treated
502 248 0   NonTreated
503 249 0   NonTreated
504 250 1   NonTreated
505 250 0   NonTreated
506 251 1   NonTreated
507 251 0   NonTreated
508 252 1   Treated
509 252 0   Treated
510 253 1   NonTreated
511 253 0   NonTreated
512 254 1   NonTreated
513 254 1   NonTreated
514 254 0   NonTreated
515 255 0   Treated
516 256 1   Treated
517 256 0   Treated
518 257 0   Treated
519 258 0   Treated
520 259 0   NonTreated
521 260 0   Treated
522 261 0   Treated
523 262 1   Treated
524 262 0   Treated
525 263 1   NonTreated
526 263 0   NonTreated
527 264 0   NonTreated
528 265 0   NonTreated
529 266 0   NonTreated
530 267 0   NonTreated
531 268 0   NonTreated
532 269 1   NonTreated
533 269 1   NonTreated
534 269 1   NonTreated
535 269 1   NonTreated
536 269 1   NonTreated
537 269 1   NonTreated
538 269 1   NonTreated
539 269 1   NonTreated
540 269 1   NonTreated
541 269 1   NonTreated
542 269 0   NonTreated
543 270 1   Treated
544 270 1   Treated
545 270 0   Treated
546 271 0   Treated
547 272 1   Treated
548 272 0   Treated
549 273 0   Treated
550 274 1   NonTreated
551 274 1   NonTreated
552 274 1   NonTreated
553 274 1   NonTreated
554 274 1   NonTreated
555 274 1   NonTreated
556 274 1   NonTreated
557 274 1   NonTreated
558 274 1   NonTreated
559 274 1   NonTreated
560 274 1   NonTreated
561 274 1   NonTreated
562 274 1   NonTreated
563 274 1   NonTreated
564 274 1   NonTreated
565 274 1   NonTreated
566 274 0   NonTreated
567 275 1   Treated
568 275 0   Treated
569 276 1   NonTreated
570 276 1   NonTreated
571 276 1   NonTreated
572 276 0   NonTreated
573 277 1   NonTreated
574 277 0   NonTreated
575 278 1   Treated
576 278 1   Treated
577 278 0   Treated
578 279 0   NonTreated
579 280 1   NonTreated
580 280 1   NonTreated
581 280 1   NonTreated
582 280 1   NonTreated
583 280 0   NonTreated
584 281 0   NonTreated
585 282 1   NonTreated
586 282 1   NonTreated
587 282 0   NonTreated
588 283 1   NonTreated
589 283 0   NonTreated
590 284 0   NonTreated
591 285 0   NonTreated
592 286 0   NonTreated
593 287 0   Treated
594 288 1   Treated
595 288 0   Treated
596 289 0   Treated
597 290 1   NonTreated
598 290 0   NonTreated
599 291 0   Treated
600 292 1   NonTreated
601 292 0   NonTreated
602 293 0   NonTreated
603 294 0   Treated
604 295 0   Treated
605 296 1   Treated
606 296 0   Treated
607 297 0   NonTreated
608 298 1   NonTreated
609 298 1   NonTreated
610 298 1   NonTreated
611 298 1   NonTreated
612 298 1   NonTreated
613 298 0   NonTreated
614 299 0   NonTreated
615 300 1   Treated
616 300 0   Treated
617 301 1   NonTreated
618 301 1   NonTreated
619 301 1   NonTreated
620 301 0   NonTreated
621 302 1   Treated
622 302 1   Treated
623 302 0   Treated
624 303 0   Treated
625 304 1   NonTreated
626 304 1   NonTreated
627 304 1   NonTreated
628 304 1   NonTreated
629 304 0   NonTreated
630 305 1   NonTreated
631 305 0   NonTreated
632 306 0   Treated
633 307 1   Treated
634 307 0   Treated
635 308 0   NonTreated
636 309 1   NonTreated
637 309 1   NonTreated
638 309 1   NonTreated
639 309 0   NonTreated
640 310 1   NonTreated
641 310 0   NonTreated
642 311 0   Treated
643 312 0   NonTreated
644 313 0   NonTreated
645 314 0   Treated
646 315 1   Treated
647 315 0   Treated
648 316 1   Treated
649 316 0   Treated
650 317 1   NonTreated
651 317 1   NonTreated
652 317 1   NonTreated
653 317 1   NonTreated
654 317 1   NonTreated
655 317 1   NonTreated
656 317 1   NonTreated
657 317 1   NonTreated
658 317 0   NonTreated
659 318 1   Treated
660 318 1   Treated
661 318 1   Treated
662 318 1   Treated
663 318 1   Treated
664 318 1   Treated
665 318 0   Treated
666 319 0   Treated
667 320 1   NonTreated
668 320 0   NonTreated
669 321 1   Treated
670 321 1   Treated
671 321 0   Treated
672 322 1   Treated
673 322 0   Treated
674 323 0   NonTreated
675 324 1   Treated
676 324 0   Treated
677 325 1   NonTreated
678 325 1   NonTreated
679 325 1   NonTreated
680 325 0   NonTreated
681 326 0   Treated
682 327 1   NonTreated
683 327 1   NonTreated
684 327 1   NonTreated
685 327 1   NonTreated
686 327 0   NonTreated
687 328 0   NonTreated
688 329 0   Treated
689 330 0   NonTreated
690 331 1   Treated
691 331 0   Treated
692 332 0   Treated
693 333 0   Treated
694 334 1   NonTreated
695 334 0   NonTreated
696 335 1   NonTreated
697 335 0   NonTreated
698 336 1   NonTreated
699 336 1   NonTreated
700 336 1   NonTreated
701 336 1   NonTreated
702 336 1   NonTreated
703 336 0   NonTreated
704 337 0   NonTreated
705 338 0   Treated
706 339 1   NonTreated
707 339 1   NonTreated
708 339 0   NonTreated
709 340 0   NonTreated
710 341 0   Treated
711 342 0   NonTreated
712 343 0   NonTreated
713 344 0   Treated
714 345 0   Treated
715 346 0   Treated
716 347 1   NonTreated
717 347 1   NonTreated
718 347 1   NonTreated
719 347 0   NonTreated
720 348 1   NonTreated
721 348 1   NonTreated
722 348 1   NonTreated
723 348 1   NonTreated
724 348 0   NonTreated
725 349 1   NonTreated
726 349 0   NonTreated
727 350 1   NonTreated
728 350 1   NonTreated
729 350 1   NonTreated
730 350 1   NonTreated
731 350 1   NonTreated
732 350 1   NonTreated
733 350 1   NonTreated
734 350 1   NonTreated
735 350 1   NonTreated
736 350 1   NonTreated
737 350 1   NonTreated
738 350 1   NonTreated
739 350 1   NonTreated
740 350 1   NonTreated
741 350 1   NonTreated
742 350 1   NonTreated
743 350 1   NonTreated
744 350 1   NonTreated
745 350 1   NonTreated
746 350 1   NonTreated
747 350 1   NonTreated
748 350 1   NonTreated
749 350 0   NonTreated
750 351 1   NonTreated
751 351 1   NonTreated
752 351 1   NonTreated
753 351 0   NonTreated
754 352 0   NonTreated
755 353 1   NonTreated
756 353 0   NonTreated
757 354 1   NonTreated
758 354 0   NonTreated
759 355 1   Treated
760 355 0   Treated
761 356 0   NonTreated
762 357 1   NonTreated
763 357 0   NonTreated
764 358 0   NonTreated
765 359 0   Treated
766 360 0   Treated
767 361 1   NonTreated
768 361 0   NonTreated
769 362 0   Treated
770 363 0   Treated
771 364 0   Treated
772 365 0   NonTreated
773 366 1   Treated
774 366 0   Treated
775 367 0   Treated
776 368 1   NonTreated
777 368 1   NonTreated
778 368 0   NonTreated
779 369 1   NonTreated
780 369 0   NonTreated
781 370 1   NonTreated
782 370 1   NonTreated
783 370 0   NonTreated
784 371 0   Treated
785 372 0   NonTreated
786 373 0   Treated
787 374 0   Treated
788 375 0   Treated
789 376 0   NonTreated
790 377 0   Treated
791 378 1   NonTreated
792 378 1   NonTreated
793 378 0   NonTreated
794 379 1   Treated
795 379 1   Treated
796 379 1   Treated
797 379 1   Treated
798 379 1   Treated
799 379 0   Treated
800 380 0   NonTreated
801 381 0   Treated
802 382 0   NonTreated
803 383 1   Treated
804 383 0   Treated
805 384 0   Treated
806 385 0   Treated
807 386 0   Treated
808 387 0   NonTreated
809 388 0   NonTreated
810 389 1   Treated
811 389 1   Treated
812 389 1   Treated
813 389 0   Treated
814 390 0   NonTreated
815 391 0   Treated
816 392 1   NonTreated
817 392 0   NonTreated
818 393 1   NonTreated
819 393 1   NonTreated
820 393 1   NonTreated
821 393 1   NonTreated
822 393 1   NonTreated
823 393 0   NonTreated
824 394 1   Treated
825 394 0   Treated
826 395 1   Treated
827 395 0   Treated
828 396 1   Treated
829 396 1   Treated
830 396 1   Treated
831 396 1   Treated
832 396 1   Treated
833 396 0   Treated
834 397 1   NonTreated
835 397 1   NonTreated
836 397 1   NonTreated
837 397 0   NonTreated
838 398 1   Treated
839 398 0   Treated
840 399 1   NonTreated
841 399 1   NonTreated
842 399 1   NonTreated
843 399 1   NonTreated
844 399 1   NonTreated
845 399 1   NonTreated
846 399 1   NonTreated
847 399 1   NonTreated
848 399 1   NonTreated
849 399 1   NonTreated
850 399 1   NonTreated
851 399 0   NonTreated
852 400 0   Treated
853 401 1   NonTreated
854 401 1   NonTreated
855 401 1   NonTreated
856 401 1   NonTreated
857 401 1   NonTreated
858 401 0   NonTreated
859 402 1   NonTreated
860 402 0   NonTreated
861 403 0   Treated
```

Comment: Please post your sample data as text within your question in order to provide a reproducible example. There may be leading blanks in your data that are affecting the result.

Comment: Thanks! I post it, I hope it's the right way to do it beacause I didn't find a way to attach the file .dta

Comment: Code blocks are lines the are indented by 4 spaces.  In the stackoverflow editor you can select the lines to be shown as code and press Ctrl-K.  Also, you typically only need to show a couple of rows instead of the entire data set.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not in the code you posten, but right before it. You did not succesfully create `readm`. To show that, run the following code:

```
proc print data=readm (obs=9);
run;
```

(The `obs=` is just there to limit the listing to 9 observations.)
Somehow, SAS must be informed your fourth column is a text column

You probably wrote someting like

```
data readm;
    infile 'C:\<some path>\<some file>';
    input Oss   id  event   chemo;
run;
```

I would read this as

```
data readm;
    infile 'C:\<some path>\<some file>' truncover dsd dlm='09'x;
    input Oss   id  event   chemo $9.;
run;
```

In this

- `dcd` specifies you have a delimiters
- `dlm='09'x` specifies your delimiters are tabs
- `$9.' specifies the chemo field is a character field of up to 9 characters.
- `truncover` specifies you do not want to read the next line to find the last characters of the 'chemo' field on the next line

If this is not realy the answer to your question, tell us how you did creat/import `readm` and we will see what we can do.

*Disclaimer: This code is not tested. If it bugs, please inform me, and I will debug it.*